Show that the interval ⟨2, 5⟩ ⊆ ℝ⁺ is an uncountable set.
Question: Show that the interval $⟨2, 5⟩ ⊆ ℝ⁺$ is an uncountable set.\
To show that the interval $ \langle 2, 5 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{R}^+ $ is an uncountable set, we can use Cantor's diagonal argument.
Assume for contradiction that $ \langle 2, 5 \rangle $ is countable. Then we can list its elements as follows:
$ x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots $
where each $ x_i $ is a real number in the interval $ \langle 2, 5 \rangle $.
Now, let's construct a number $ y $ such that its $ i $th decimal digit is different from the $ i $th decimal digit of $ x_i $.
Then, $ y $ is a real number in the interval $ \langle 2, 5 \rangle $, but it is not in our list because it differs from each $ x_i $ at least in one decimal place. This contradicts the assumption that we could list all the elements of $ \langle 2, 5 \rangle $.
Therefore, $ \langle 2, 5 \rangle $ is uncountable.
Is this correct approach or am I doing something wrong?

It's correct if you can show construction of $y$ s.t. it's in $(2, 5)$.

Another approach might be to find a bijection between $(2,5)$ and $\mathbb R$

It's correct. As @J.W.Tanner pointed out, you can also show that there exists a bijection $f : (2,5)\to\mathbb R$, even though in that case you'd be assuming that $\mathbb R$ is uncountable in the first place. Anyways, a simple bijection could be $f(x) = \tan\left(\dfrac\pi3x-2+\dfrac\pi2\right)$, the domain being of course $(2,5)$.
